# How can I pass back the selected radiobutton in a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass in a dynamic list of radiobuttonitems, and get back the selected radio button along with other model information.

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
public class MyFormModel
{
    public List<MyItem> RadioItems;
    public String SomeQuestion;
    public String SelectedButton { get; set; }
    public String Answer { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = new List<MyItem>();
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Id = 1, Name = "Male", Selected = true });
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Female", Selected = false });
        var m = new MyFormModel();
        m.RadioItems = items;
        m.SomeQuestion = "What's your favorite color?";
        return View(m);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyFormModel model)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(model.Answer); //works
        Console.WriteLine(model.SelectedButton); //does not work
        return null;
    }
```

View

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.MyFormModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    foreach (var r in Model.RadioItems)
    {
        @Html.RadioButton("MyGroup",r.Id,r.Selected)  @Html.Label(r.Name)<br/>
    }
    @Html.Label(Model.SomeQuestion)    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Answer)
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

What do I need to do so that on the postback I can determine the selected radio button?  I must be missing something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has to match the view, so either change the view to

```
 @Html.RadioButton("SelectedButton",r.Id,r.Selected)
```

or add

```
public string MyGroup {get;set;}
```

to your model.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the "selected" radio button to your model in your Html Helper.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedButton, "false")
```

Comment: The user can change the button.  I need to get that in the postback

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit yes, whatever the value is at the time of the post, it will be saved in the model.